# Is the result still true if we drop completeness?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I know how to prove the following exercise ( from Folland) :

> If $X$, $Y$ are Banach spaces. $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is a linear map such that $f\circ T\in\operatorname{dual}(X)$ whenever $f\in \operatorname{dual}(Y)$, then $T$ is bounded.

Now I want to know whether the result is still true if $X$ and $Y$ are just normed vector spaces instead of Banach spaces.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your argument for the Banach space case? It is important to identify where you use the completeness property.

Comment: From the given condition I proved that T is a closed linear operator , then by the closed graph theorem it follows that T is bounded. Now to use that theorem we need completeness of both X AND Y.

Comment: It seems that with Baire's theorem, the result still holds when only $X$ is assumed to be a Banach space. So the question remains when we drop completeness of $X$.